# Android how to access the location data in a jpg

Tags: android, gps, photo, jpeg

I'm making an Android app that includes a feature to show images on a map.

How can I extract the location data from a .jpg file (if there is location data)?

Many thanks, Todd.

Comment: Take a look at this, I think this is exactly what you want:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9868158/get-gps-location-of-a-photo][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9868158/get-gps-location-of-a-photo

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is nice tutorial how to access exif data (that includes GPS info you need) from jpg that can help you:
http://android-coding.blogspot.com/2011/10/read-exif-of-jpg-file-using.html

The corresponding class is described in official docs:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html

Also useful post (convert GPS info) can be found:
http://android-coding.blogspot.com/2011/10/convert-gps-tag-of-exifinterface-to.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33798250/how-to-get-location-and-other-information-from-image-in-android

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I did it:

```
    try {
      final ExifInterface exifInterface = new ExifInterface(imagePath);
      float[] latLong = new float[2];
      if (exifInterface.getLatLong(latLong)) {
        // Do stuff with lat / long...
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      logger.info("Couldn't read exif info: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
```